# Confused in use of 'a' and 'the'

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I am confused whether I can use 'a' or 'the' in this sentence:

> While he was walking down ___  street.

The word "street" has been used in the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. To get a proper answer, you will need to supply  the context of the issue you have.  Otherwise any answer will be a guess.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is - **the**

You use **the**  when we are talking about a specific person or thing, or if there is only one, or if it is clear which one we are talking about.

You use **a** when we are talking about something for the first time.

Here, since street has been already used at the beginning of the statement, **the** seems most appropriate.

Comment: What if the blank sentece is used in the beginning of the passage..

Comment: In that case it will be "a" because it is not clear from the context which road are we talking about.